# show ad after # paragraphs

Tags: post-meta

Trying to use ACF to determine when to insert an ad after # many paragraphs. Right now after `3` paragraphs the ad is inserted.

```
if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
    $show_after = get_field('show_after');
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 3, $content );
}
```

I'm having issues mapping `3` to the variable `$show_after`. Returns nothing in below code:

```
if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
    $show_after = get_field('show_after');
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $show_after, $content );
}
```

Is there any way I can map the `3` to a variable so the poster can input the paragraph amount?

Comment: This question is not actually about ACF, so you are in luck ;) As by the rules of this site, third-party plugins are offtopic, and should be dealt with in their respective support forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `post_meta` field to let an author decide after how many paragraphs the ad is inserted, if you want to do it like that, and not with a shortcode.

So create a custom field called `f711_insert_after_no_p`, and use your function like this:

```
if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
    $show_after = get_field('show_after');
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'f711_insert_after_no_p', true ), $content );
}
```

Be sure to validate the input to only allow integers, or do this in the output.

I think for ACF the code (instead of `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'f711_insert_after_no_p', true )` ) would be

```
get_the_field( 'f711_insert_after_no_p' )
```

Comment: Worked as intended! Perfect.